# Eliminate parent element with CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, html

Is there a way to eliminate parent element while keeping current element?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/KZd67/)'s my example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <span>some text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
div
{
    padding: 20px;
}
#parent
{
    background-color: green;
}
#child
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to replace the parent div with `child` div. Meaning I take `#parent`'s parent, and replace its inner html with `#child`.
I tried playing with visibility but it still takes up the space or hides entire tree.
Is there a CSS way? Otherwise how should it be done easily with jQuery? (note that in my real scenario it's some level up).

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the padding on the parent? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KZd67/2/

Comment: @j08691. No. I don't want the element in the DOM at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)**:

> Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM,
>   leaving the matched elements in their place.

```
$('#child').unwrap();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZd67/1/)**

Comment: I'll use a `while` statement to check parent's name and run `unwrap` in a loop until desired parent is reached. Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing with `.unwrap();` method and `.html();`:

With`.unwrap()` (*preferred way*):

```
$('#child').unwrap();
```

---

With `.html();`:

```
var o = $('#child').html();
$('#parent`).html(o);
```